# Analytic continuation of $\alpha(s)=\sum_{n=a+1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n^2-a^2)^s}$. Possibly related to Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s)$?

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, functional-equations, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation

I'm trying to find the analytic continuation for

$\alpha(s)=\sum_{n=a+1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n^2-a^2)^s} ,$

with $a\in \mathbb{N^+}$ and $s<1$. I need most likely only the values for $s=\frac{1}{2}-m$ with $m\in\mathbb{N^+_0}$ if that matters.

If there is any "simple" relation to the Riemann Zeta function (or related functions like Hurwitz Zeta, Multiple Zeta, etc.); I can't see it.

Although I'm familiar with the concept of analytic continuation, I don't really know how to progress and get to a (at least numerically) usable result for $\alpha(s)$. I'm an engineer, so I appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Thank you for any comments.

Comment: Expand $n^{-2s} (1-a^2 n^{-2})^{-s}$ with the binomial series (see some of  [those](https://mathoverflow.net/users/84768/reuns?tab=answers) answers)